# Max on create date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this procedure that is returning three records and I need it to only return the row with the max date. I have created a function to pass comma delimited values.  It returns multi records for the values being passed. I need it to return only the record with the max date.  I think I missing something simple.  Thanks in Advance

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
         ZITMTSICOD6.LNGDES_0 as variety
        ,STOLOT.YCROPYR_0 as crop_year
        ,STOLOT.LOT_0 as lot_number
        ,ZITMTSICOD2.LNGDES_0 AS product_name
        ,ISNULL([UV_Alpha], 'NA') as uv_alpha
        ,ISNULL([UV_Beta], 'NA') as uv_beta
        ,ISNULL([HSI], 'NA') as hsi
        ,ISNULL(Moisture, 'NA') as moisture
        ,ISNULL(Oil_by_Dist,'NA') as oil_by_dist
        ,ISNULL([HPLC Alpha],'NA') as hplc_alpha
        ,ISNULL([HPLC Beta],'NA') as hplc_beta
        ,ISNULL([HPLC Cohumulone],'NA') as hplc_cohumulone
        ,ISNULL([HPLC Colupulone],'NA') as hplc_colupulone
        ,ISNULL([Mebak Alpha 7.5],'NA') as mebak_alpha_7_5
        ,ISNULL([LCV Alpha 7.4],'NA') as lcv_alpha_7_4
        ,ISNULL(Oil_B_Pinene,'NA') as oil_b_pinene
        ,ISNULL(Oil_Myrcene,'NA') as oil_myrcene
        ,ISNULL(Oil_Linalool,'NA') as oil_linalool
        ,ISNULL(Oil_Caryophyllene,'NA') as oil_caryophyllene
        ,ISNULL(Oil_Farnesene,'NA') as oil_farnesene
        ,ISNULL(Oil_Humulene,'NA') as oil_humulene
        ,ISNULL(Oil_Geraniol,'NA') as oil_geraniol
        ,STOQLYH.CREDAT_0 as created_at

    FROM
    LIVE.STOLOT 
        left outer join
    LIVE.STOQLYD on STOLOT.LOT_0 = STOQLYD.LOT_0 and STOLOT.SLO_0 = 
    STOQLYD.SLO_0 and STOQLYD.ITMREF_0 = STOLOT.ITMREF_0
        left outer join
    LIVE.STOQLYH on STOQLYH.VCRNUM_0 = STOQLYD.VCRNUM_0 and STOQLYH.ITMREF_0 
   = STOQLYD.ITMREF_0
        left outer join
    LIVE.ITMMASTER on STOLOT.ITMREF_0 = ITMMASTER.ITMREF_0
        left outer join
    LIVE.ZITMTSICOD6 on ITMMASTER.TSICOD_6 = ZITMTSICOD6.ID_0
        left outer join
    LIVE.ZITMTSICOD2 on ITMMASTER.TSICOD_2 = ZITMTSICOD2.ID_0
        left outer join

    (

    SELECT 
        QLYCTLDEM_0,
        QLYCRDASW.VCRLIN_0,
        ITMREF_0,
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'UVALP110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'UV_Alpha',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'UVBET110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'UV_Beta',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'UVHSI110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'HSI',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'OVMOI110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Moisture',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'DIOIL110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Oil_by_Dist',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'HPALP110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'HPLC Alpha',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'HPBET110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'HPLC Beta',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'HPCOH110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'HPLC Cohumulone',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'HPCOL110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'HPLC Colupulone',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'LCALP110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Mebak Alpha 7.5',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'LCALP310' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'LCV Alpha 7.4',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'GCBPI110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Oil_B_Pinene',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'GCMYR110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Oil_Myrcene',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'GCLIN110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Oil_Linalool',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'GCCAR110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Oil_Caryophyllene',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'GCFAR110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Oil_Farnesene',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'GCHUM110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Oil_Humulene',
        MAX(CASE WHEN QLYCRDASW.QSTNUM_0 = 'GCGEL110' THEN QLYCRDASW.ASW_0 
 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Oil_Geraniol'
    FROM 
        LIVE.QLYCRDASW 
 GROUP BY QLYCTLDEM_0, QLYCRDASW.VCRLIN_0, ITMREF_0


    ) AS QLYCRDASW 
    ON (STOQLYD.VCRNUM_0 = QLYCRDASW.QLYCTLDEM_0) AND (STOQLYD.VCRLIN_0 = 
   QLYCRDASW.VCRLIN_0) AND (STOQLYD.ITMREF_0 = QLYCRDASW.ITMREF_0)
    WHERE STOLOT.LOT_0 In( 
    SELECT Item 
       --FROM dbo.SplitString('17-OR277-001,PL1-YKUCTZ0012,DZJ25168',','))
        FROM dbo.SplitString('PL1-YKUCTZ0012',','))

       and (ISNUMERIC(UV_Alpha) = 1 or ISNUMERIC(UV_Beta) = 1 or 
 ISNUMERIC(HSI) = 1 or ISNUMERIC(Moisture) = 1 and ISNUMERIC(Oil_by_Dist) = 1 
 or ISNUMERIC([HPLC Alpha]) = 1
        or ISNUMERIC([HPLC Beta]) = 1 or ISNUMERIC([HPLC Cohumulone]) = 1 or 
ISNUMERIC([HPLC Colupulone]) = 1 or ISNUMERIC([Mebak Alpha 7.5]) = 1 or 
ISNUMERIC([LCV Alpha 7.4]) = 1
        or ISNUMERIC(Oil_B_Pinene) = 1  or ISNUMERIC(Oil_Myrcene) = 1 or 
ISNUMERIC(Oil_Linalool) = 1 or ISNUMERIC(Oil_Caryophyllene) = 1 or 
ISNUMERIC(Oil_Farnesene) = 1 or ISNUMERIC(Oil_Humulene) = 1
        or ISNUMERIC(Oil_Geraniol) = 1)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Something simple like `TOP 1`?

Comment: top 1 only returns the top for my first vaule it does not go on the my second

Comment: I'd be careful with all that `ISNUMERIC` usage. Many people think it does one thing, when it's actually computes something entirely different. If you are aware of this, then disregard. i.e. `select isnumeric('1e4'), isnumeric('$')`. For your other issue, you'll want to use `with ties` or a window function like `row_number()`

Comment: I think you need to add sample data and desired results.   Your question says you only want the row with the max date, which sounds to me like you only want one row.   If  that's not what you want, you need to make the question clearer.

Comment: You did ask for the row with the max date.

Comment: Ever find your answer?  From what you said, it sounds like DENSE_RANK is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a form of RANK, probably DENSE_RANK?  Here's a good site to explain them.  You'd add that in the query and wrap the whole thing in another query, then add WHERE RankedColumn = 1. Make sense?

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/rank-denserank-and-rownumber-functions-in-sql-server/